# MFSideMenu menuContainerViewController is nil

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use MFSideMenu but when I ask for the menu to open the app breaks because menuContainerViewController is empty

This is the code that creates the menu at appDelegate (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions):

```
 let s = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let contentView = s.instantiateInitialViewController()
        let leftMenu = s.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftMenuViewController") as! LeftMenuViewController

        let container:MFSideMenuContainerViewController = MFSideMenuContainerViewController.containerWithCenterViewController(contentView, leftMenuViewController: leftMenu, rightMenuViewController: nil)

        window?.rootViewController = container
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

this is the code responsible for opening my menu:

```
self.menuContainerViewController.toggleLeftSideMenuCompletion({})
```

what might be happening? I installed the library using CocoaPods and I'm importing it properly.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one,

```
self.menuContainerViewController.toggleLeftSideMenuCompletion(nil)
```